# Route::resource clean /public from URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am making a system using the **Laravel 5.6**

I uploaded to a server that I have and access this externally

You used the software when a route uses resouce, for example::

```
Route::resource('materiais', 'MaterialController');
```

Because the routes you create using `Route::get`, `Route::post`, `Route::patch`, etc.., work correctly

For example, if I'm in

`http://192.168.0.23/sisobras/public/neworder`

and I go to open a new order he goes to the address

`http://192.168.0.23/sisobras/public/serviceorder/2/create?`

running correctly, a route looks like this:

`Route::get('serviceorder/{id}/create', 'ServiceOrderController@create');`

but if I'm in

`http://192.168.0.23/sisobras/public/materials`

and you can register new material the url looks like this:

`http://192.168.0.23/materials/create`

The view is called on the controller so

```
public function create()
{
    $units = Units::all();
    return view('materials/create', compact('units'));
}
```

and the lack of `sisobras/public/` a `Not Found` error

When used with the `php artisan serve` works correctly

Comment: your question is unclear. how is the url `http://192.168.0.23/materials/create` being created? is it in one of your views? you need to correctly configure 'laravel in a subfolder' first. additionally, does `http://192.168.0.23/sisobras/.env` display your .env? it shouldnt. look at https://laravel-news.com/subfolder-install for help here.

Comment: @BenSholdice I added some information to improve the explanation